# phylogenetic relationships in sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server, phylogeny

I am somewhat a novice in SQL and I am currently trying to set up  a query that will enable me to pull phylogenetic relationships out of a database. I have a tabel (Yeast) filled with yeast strain data. All individual strains have a unique identifier (ID) as well as an ancestorID (the ID og the parent strain it has been derived from). My issue is that I would like to have a complete overview of parental strains not just the parent strain but also the grand parents, grandgrand parents and so on. Additionally if possible it would be really nice if it was possible to show all siblings at the different levels as well. Can any one help me?
edit:
The result I would like to get from the query would look something like the picture in the link (
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tmvWP.png). This is the result I would hope to get if I run the query inputting ID=40388. (40388, 40389, 40390, 40391, 40392) siblings with child/parent relationship to 37829 which again has a parent/ child relationship to 36139. The whole database contains more than 40K entries so I cannot include it in here.

Comment: Please be more specific about what you are trying to achieve.  Is the question about `supplying a strain's id, and returning all ancestors`?  Is the question about an alternative way to represent the hierarchical relationships?  To improve this question please show a replicable use case; some example / sample data representing your `yeast` table, a concrete example / description of the exact task you need to perform (including any parameters), and the exact results you'd want when using your example data.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: It is as you describe at first i.e. supplying a strain ID and returning the ancestors and the ancestors ancestors untill the AncestorID is Null. I have included a small subsample of the table where I have made mulitple queries to establish the parentage. In this case I knew the parent/child relationships which I do not do.ID AncestorID
40388 37829
40389 37829
40390 37829
40391 37829
40392 37829
37829 36139

Comment: Please edit the question to put examples in there, where they can be formatted for readability *(both the example of the `yeast` table, and the corresponding results you'd want)*.  Also, please could you add the tag for whichever database you're using?  Some support recursion, others do not.